# Is it possible to do an out-of-source build with bjam?

Tags: bjam, boost-build

Due to quota restrictions I really need to build a project that I'm working on with all of the temporary files and build products in a separate directory (in my case `/tmp/somewhere`).

I'm used to doing this with CMake, is it possible with `bjam`, if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. In your project declaration you can specify the `build-dir` location to anything you like instead of the default local `bin.v2` location (see [projects](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/release/index.html#bbv2.overview.projects)).